# Speedup for the reduce operation in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, gpgpu, theano

**Edit**:
So sorry, it turns out that I had other processes running on my GPU while I did the test, I've updated the timing results on an idle GPU, and the speedup becomes noticeable for larger matrices.

Original Post:

As posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511680/loop-over-or-vectorize-variable-length-matrices-using-theano), `L` is a list of matrices, where each item `M` is a `x*n` matrix (`x` is a variable, `n` is fixed).

I want to compute the sum of `M'*M` for all items in `L` (`M'` is the transpose of `M`) as the following Python code does.

```
for M in L:
  res += np.dot(M.T, M)
```

Followings are some examples of Numpy and Theano implementations (for executable script please refer to @DanielRenshaw's answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34512763/3041068)).

```
def numpy_version1(*L):
    n = L[0].shape[1]
    res = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=L[0].dtype)
    for M in L:
        res += np.dot(M.T, M)
    return res

def compile_theano_version1(number_of_matrices, n, dtype):
    L = [tt.matrix() for _ in xrange(number_of_matrices)]
    res = tt.zeros(n, dtype=dtype)
    for M in L:
        res += tt.dot(M.T, M)
    return theano.function(L, res)

def compile_theano_version2(number_of_matrices, n):
    L = theano.typed_list.TypedListType(tt.TensorType(theano.config.floatX, broadcastable=(None, None)))()
    res, _ = theano.reduce(fn=lambda i, tmp: tmp+tt.dot(L[i].T, L[i]),
                           outputs_info=tt.zeros((n, n), dtype=theano.config.floatX),
                           sequences=[theano.tensor.arange(number_of_matrices, dtype='int64')])
    return theano.function([L], res)
```

I ran the Numpy version on CPU, and Theano versions on GPU with different  settings, it seems that the Theano versions are always proportionally slower than the Numpy version (regardless of the number and size of matices).

But I was expecting there could be some optimization w.r.t GPU as it is a simple reduce operation.

Could someone help me understand what's going on under the hood?

Edit:
Followings are the script (from @DanielRenshaw) for generating data, settings I've tired and results.

```
L = [np.random.standard_normal(size=(x, n)).astype(dtype)
     for x in range(min_x, number_of_matrices + min_x)]

dtype = 'float32'
theano.config.floatX = dtype
iteration_count = 10
min_x = 20

# base case:
# numpy_version1 0.100589990616
# theano_version1 0.243968963623
# theano_version2 0.198153018951
number_of_matrices = 200
n = 100

# increase matrix size:
# numpy_version1 4.90120816231
# theano_version1 0.984472036362
# theano_version2 3.56008815765
number_of_matrices = 200
n = 1000

# increase number of matrices:
# numpy_version1 5.11445093155
# theano_version1 compilation error
# theano_version2 6.54448604584
number_of_matrices = 2000
n = 100
```

Comment: Which GPU do you have? That might be the key to the answer. If you have the latest i7, and the crapiest GPU, doesn't matter how big the array is, a CPU version will probably be faster, specially if you have numpy built with MKL, OpenBLAS, etc.. which uses all the cores for dot operations.

Comment: @imaluengo am using i7, nvidia titan x, and numpy is built with OpenBLAS

Comment: Ops, then that shouldn't be the case :P Can you add the values of `L` and size of `M` you have tried in tests, and the results you got (at least some of them)?

Comment: @imaluengo thanks I'll add them shortly.

Comment: It is just so I can replicate the exact results. Easier to test what is going wrong.

Comment: @imaluengo hi, I've added some results, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having, is not the *number* of matrices, is the *size* of them.

Your test example, creates matrices of size dependent on the number of matrices you have, thus, the more matrices you have the larger the matrices are, but also the larger the python loop overhead is (in reduce operations), and thus, it makes harder to detect speed improvements.

I've sightly modify your matrix generation in order to make some new tests:

```
S = 1000 # Size of the matrices
N = 10 # Number of matrices

L = [np.random.standard_normal(size=(np.random.randint(S//2, S*2), S)).astype(np.float32) for _ in range(N)]
```

This generates only 10 matrices of size `(x, 1000)` where `x` is some value in the range of `[S//2, S*2] == [500, 2000]`.

```
f1 = compile_theano_version1(N, S, np.float32)
f2 = compile_theano_version2(N, S)
```

---

- Now some tests with `N = 10` big matrices:

For `S = 1000`, `N = 10`:

```
 %timeit numpy_version1(*L)   # 10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop
 %timeit f1(*L)               # 10 loops, best of 3: 37.3 ms per loop
 %timeit f2(L)                # 10 loops, best of 3: 68.7 ms per loop
```

where theano functions have a `x4` and `x2` speedup in a laptop with a pretty nice `i7` and a decent NVIDIA 860M (which means that you should get some nicer speedups here).

For `S = 5000`, `N = 10`:

```
 %timeit numpy_version1(*L)   # 1 loops, best of 3: 4 s per loop
 %timeit f1(*L)               # 1 loops, best of 3: 907 ms per loop
 %timeit f2(L)                # 1 loops, best of 3: 1.77 s per loop
```

So, overall, with this setup the larger the `S` the larger the speedup theano gets over the CPU.

---

- Some tests with `N = 100` big matrices: theano seems faster

For `S = 1000`, `N = 100`:

```
%timeit numpy_version1(*L)   # 1 loops, best of 3: 1.46 s per loop
%timeit f1(*L)               # 1 loops, best of 3: 408 ms per loop
%timeit f2(L)                # 1 loops, best of 3: 724 s per loop
```

For `S = 2000`, `N = 100`:

```
%timeit numpy_version1(*L)   # 1 loops, best of 3: 11.3 s per loop
%timeit f1(*L)               # 1 loops, best of 3: 2.72 s per loop
%timeit f2(L)                # 1 loops, best of 3: 4.01 s per loop
```

---

- Tests with `N = 100` small matrices: numpy seems faster

For `S = 50`, `N = 100`:

```
%timeit numpy_version1(*L)   # 100 loops, best of 3: 1.17 ms per loop
%timeit f1(*L)               # 100 loops, best of 3: 4.21 ms per loop
%timeit f2(L)                # 100 loops, best of 3: 7.42 ms per loop
```

---

Specifications for the tests:

- Processor: i7 4710HQ
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M
- Numpy: version 1.10.2 built with intel MKT
- Theano: version 0.70; floatX = float32; using GPU

Comment: The other factor that plays a part is the overhead of copying data between main memory and GPU memory. The CPU version avoids this overhead altogether but it's unclear to me right now how varying the hyperparameters will affect the GPU speed. It really needs to be tested in a real use context, not in an artificial situation like this.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw yep, is hard to say in a real context what would the real speedup be. All I can do right now is add more synthetic tests :P Just added more tests with larger `N` (number of matrices), and the speed up keeps going up.  With smaller `S` (size of matrices) numpy seems to be faster (as I woudl expect) as the overhead of copying the matrix to GPU is larger than the speedup obtained by multiplying it in the GPU.